# Running PHP script for inserting into database

Tags: php, sql

I am working on a PHP script to loop through a file to insert into the a database. Current the script is working but it is not inserting to the database. I have the connection working properly and I echo out the result just to ensure it is correct. It looks lines and loops accordingly (there is a lot more then 3 records but I did that for test purpose.

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $dbusername, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$myfile = fopen("words_alpha.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");

//For Each line
$index = 1;
while($index <= 3){
    $line = fgets($myfile);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO WORD (wordID, `WORD`) VALUES (NULL,'$line');";   
    echo $sql;
    $conn->query($sql); //We should be inserting here
    echo "Success <br />\n"; 
    sleep(1);
    $index++;
}
```

Worth noting wordID is a PK and is incremented automatically hence the NULL value.

Comment: "the script is working but it is not inserting to the database" --- if it's not doing the job it's intended to do it's the opposite of "working".

Comment: You don't check for errors, you don't use prepared statements (or at least escape sql string literals), a lot could go wrong.

Comment: Your insert is not ideal, but should be working.  Is there any error message?  Did you check the `WORD` table in MySQL?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I meant compiling and running. It runs the insert statement I'm assuming because it prints out success. Yes checked the database that is how I determined it didn't work. I know the INSERT isn't ideal, but I just tried copying straight from the mySQL generator just to ensure it wasn't expecting a weird syntax because I'm running a cheap webhost for class.

Comment: What exactly is `$conn`? How does it handle errors?

Comment: @zerkms added a little bit more code to the original post.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php --- check how to enable error reporting. Set it to `MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT`

Answer (score -2):

Okay try this and see is your file is readable, means stream is able to read data from filesystem ! if yes then we can write more code to save text lines in Database

```
 <?php
$file = fopen("test.txt","r");

while(! feof($file))
  {
  echo fgets($file). "<br />";
  }

fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: Such a weird issue still nothing. WORD is set out to be varchar, and is allocated to 255 so no issues there. We know we have a valid connection so no idea where the problem lies.

Comment: It's okay to pass null to the autoincrement column, and `fclose` in this code changes nothing.

Comment: updations! lets test if works fine then go to next step "Save in database"

Comment: @DupinderSingh "lets test if works" --- it makes no sense to try random irrelevant things and expect it to magically works, while you can enable error reporting and know it for sure.

Answer (score -2):

Try This Code

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","db name");

$sql = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO WORD (`WORD`) VALUES ('$line')");
```

Answer (score -2):

I couldn't notice your file reading so I thought I should point this out:

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $dbusername, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$myfile = fopen("words_alpha.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");

//For Each line
while(! feof($myfile))  {
    $line = fgets($myfile);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO WORD (wordID, `WORD`) VALUES (NULL,'$line');";   
    echo $sql;
    $conn->query($sql); //We should be inserting here
    echo "Success <br />\n";
}
fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: So what's the difference here in your code?

Comment: What you added is what I had before but I noticed it never was inserting so I did first 3 lines to prevent it from taking forever.

Comment: @user11295998 I commented with a suggestion what to do next, none of the currently posted answers target your real problem.

Comment: @zerkms I was able to enable error logging and get it fixed! Thanks!